# How do I solve this error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, rx-java, retrofit2

I am working on a project with a django restframework backend ,I have done the backend and tested it's working properly but now I want to connect my android application to the APIs but it is at this point that I want to fetch this resposnse[image] after a successfully registration and get some data to use in the next activity that I'm getting an error although data is saved in the database

**Here is my APIClient Interface class**

```
package com.example.covid_19_tracker.data.network;
import com.example.covid_19_tracker.data.network.model.AddLocationResponse;
import com.example.covid_19_tracker.data.network.model.LoginResponse;
import com.example.covid_19_tracker.data.network.model.RegisterDeviceResponse;
import com.example.covid_19_tracker.data.network.model.RegisterUserResponse;

import java.util.HashMap;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import retrofit2.http.FieldMap;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface ApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/locations/")
    Observable<AddLocationResponse> addLocation(@FieldMap HashMap<String, Object> params);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/devices/")
    Observable<RegisterDeviceResponse> registerDevice(@FieldMap HashMap<String, Object>   params);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/accounts/register/")
    Observable<RegisterUserResponse> registerUser(@FieldMap HashMap<String, Object> params);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/accounts/login/")
    Observable<LoginResponse> loginUser(@FieldMap HashMap<String, Object> params);
}
```

**And here is my RegisterUserResponse.java model Class**

```
package com.example.covid_19_tracker.data.network.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RegisterUserResponse {
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private String success;
    @SerializedName("status_code")
    @Expose
    private Integer status_code;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    private String token;

    public RegisterUserResponse() {
    }

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public Integer getStatus_code() {
        return status_code;
    }

    public void setStatus_code(Integer status_code) {
        this.status_code = status_code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ArrayList getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**
I'm a beginner in android. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data field is not an ArrayList as you specified in your `RegisterUserResponse` class

You need to create a `Data` class that will contains the fields `id` `username` `password`...

and then in your `RegisterUserResponse`  class you will declare :

```
@SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private Data data;
```

instead of :

```
@SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
```